# Fluent Validation rules not returning the correct error code

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

Using Fluent Validation, I want to validate the following class:

```cs
public class Saloon
{
    public SaloonTypeEnum SaloonType { get; set; }
    public Percentage2TypeEnum? Percentage2Type { get; set; }
    public int? Percentage1 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to validate the class for the following conditions:

When `SaloonType` is `Rate` or `Table`, either `Percentage2Type` or `Percentage1` must be provided, but not both at the same time, and the two must not be null (either one or the other, not both).

I have these Fluent Validation rules to validate the conditions:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage1).NotNull().When(x => x!.SaloonType == SaloonTypeEnum.Rate || x.SaloonType == SaloonTypeEnum.Table);
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage1).Null().When(x => x.Percentage2Type != Percentage2TypeEnum.None);
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type).NotNull().When(x => x!.SaloonType == SaloonTypeEnum.Rate || x.SaloonType == SaloonTypeEnum.Table);
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type).Equal(Percentage2TypeEnum.None).When(x => x.Percentage1 != null);
```

For the following examples, I expect a code 400 for validation errors, but I get a 200 (using Swagger for documentation):

> Percentage2Type=null and Percentage1 = null --> should return 400
>
> Percentage2Type= 1 and Percentage1 = 2 --> should return 400

Do you see where I'm going wrong with the rules, please?

Comment: I don't see your provided code is compilable. 1. Where/What is the `Type` as `x.Type`, is the `Type` refer to `SaloonType`? 2. You are using `SaloonType` enum in the validation rule, but you are referring the `SaloonTypeEnum` in the class, same goes for `Percentage2Type` and `Percentage2TypeEnum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues & Concerns**

Besides those two concerns mentioned in the comment,

1. `Type` does not exist in the `Saloon` class, do you mean `SaloonType`?
2. Naming conflict for the enum: `SaloonType` vs `SaloonTypeEnum` and `Percentage2Type` vs `Percentage2TypeEnum`.
3. `Percentage1` is not possible to assign with `null` as it is not nullable (`int`). It will be initialized with the default value (0) if you are not assigning any value to it.
4. Same goes to `Percentage2Type`. You can't assign `null` when it is not nullable.

Assume that you have resolved the mentioned issues for example:

```cs
public class Saloon
{
    public SaloonType Type { get; set; }
    public Percentage2Type? Percentage2Type { get; set; }
    public int? Percentage1 { get; set; }
}

public enum SaloonType
{
    Rate = 1,
    Table
}

public enum Percentage2Type
{
    None,
    One
}
```

You should add two rules to validate:

1. Both `Percentage1` and `Percentage2Type` cannot be `null`.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type).NotNull()
    .When(x => x.Percentage1 == null);
```

2. `Percentage2Type` cannot be 1 (`Percentage2Type.One`) when `Percentage1` is 2.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type)
    .NotEqual(Percentage2Type.One)
    .When(x => x.Percentage1 == 2);
```

You can add another 2 rules by reversing the logic and applying to the `Percentage1`, but to me, it sounds redundant as the field depends on another field.

The complete validation rules:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type).NotNull()
    .When(x => x.Percentage1 == null);

RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type)
    .NotEqual(Percentage2Type.One)
    .When(x => x.Percentage1 == 2);

RuleFor(x => x.Percentage1)
    .NotNull()
    .When(x => x!.Type == SaloonType.Rate || x.Type == SaloonType.Table);

RuleFor(x => x.Percentage1)
    .Null()
    .When(x => x.Percentage2Type != Percentage2Type.None);

RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type)
    .NotNull()
    .When(x => x.Type == SaloonType.Rate || x.Type == SaloonType.Table);

RuleFor(x => x.Percentage2Type)
    .Equal(Percentage2Type.None)
    .When(x => x.Percentage1 != null);
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7KNYDL)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and explanation. Indeed, there are some typos in the provided class. For 1) Yes, I meant `SaloonType` as name for the `SaloonTypeEnum`. 2) I'm sorry, but I do not have a naming conflict when using `SaloonType` and `Percentage2Type` with their enum types. 3) Yes, `Percentage1` and `PercentageType2` are nullable. I'll correct those in my post. Thanks again for the logic, this works.